# How to setup up a background thread/task which triggers UI updates?

Tags: c#, architecture, multithreading, inversion-of-control

### Background

I'm designing a round-based game where one of the core design goals is to have a highly exchangable UI. For this, I've defined an interface which allows implementers to only focus on drawing the UI and processing user input - Everything else happens behind the interface.

The general idea is to have a controller in a background thread/task which calls methods on the interface (synchronously?) which are supposed to block the background thread, while asynchronously playing an animation or waiting for user input. Once the animation finished, or the user pressed/tapped on a button, the background worker shall continue its work.

### Solution Strategy

The basic idea is similar to this example:

[image: Main method creates Controller and SampleUI, which both depend on an IUserInterface interface. Controller and SampleUI don't know each other]

Note: userInterface is a member of `Controller` of type `IUserInterface`. `SampleUI` implements `IUserInterface`. The image above is the way this is represented in the `Modelio` modelling tool.

The intended workflow is like this:

[image]

Basically, the UI merely reacts - it does not control anything other than actual drawing.

### Technical discussion

The UI will be implemented using C#. It would be preferrable to have a solution which is not specific to Windows Forms, WPF, WebGL or similar.

In a classical example, I would start background work in an async UI method and await a `Task`. However, since we're having `Inversion of Control` here, I don't have that option.

What would be the right, modern, C# way of implementing this?

I have found [this arcticle from 2009](https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2009/01/23/synchronizing-calls-to-the-ui-in-a-multi-threaded-application/) which would basically recommend a background `Thread` and calling UI methods through a `Synchronization Context`. I would have to make sure the background thread does not continue execution while waiting for the UI thread but this should be easily possible.

Is there are safer / more modern way than doing this?

Comment: Why does inverting control preclude the use of Tasks?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The UI shall not know about the existence of `Controller` and therefore cannot call any methods on the object. Maybe `Dependency Inversion` would fit better?

Comment: OK, but you have an intermediary object in your diagram between the UI and the Controller for decoupling purposes.  Surely that can hold a Task?

Comment: The intermediary interface is supposed to be a classical `interface`, i.e. have only pure virtual methods. Feel free to provide an answer which involves an actual object as a matter of communication, though I would prefer if the UI does not even know about the things being done in background at all.

Comment: It wouldn't have to.  Your UI can still conform to the interface you have provided, and so can the intermediary object.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Comment: im not clear on the goal. do you actually need to block a thread, or do you just need a signal when the animation finishes?

Comment: @Ewan either is fine.. The background worker could be blocked or idle.

Comment: you say "the ui merely reacts" but then you have a button?

Comment: @Ewan The idea is that the controller tells the UI to receive a choice from the user and then return that. The UI is free to decide how to do that, a button is an example

Comment: so a standard approach in WPF would be to have the button bound to a command on your viewmodel and the animation start bound to a property change event on your viewmodel. You could use some trickery to block a thread while you waited, but I think it would be a bad design to do so

Comment: tell us your actual real game example of what you are trying to achieve